# back to original location after post

Tags: php, jquery

the web im working on is basically contained in one file with n lot of jquery `.hide and .show()` calls.

So now Im posting a form and using n different php file to handle the submit.

after processing all that is needed I tried toe use `header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);` to get back to the main page.

But the "`.hide() and .show()`" location that I was at is now reverted to as if you just opend the page for the first time.

Can you in some way call n jquery function on `header` or send some message back from the post handling script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey why don't you use jQuery to POST to the that different page like

```
$("#formname").submit(function() {
 var url = "second.php"; // the script where you handle the form input.

 $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: url,
     data: $("#formname").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
     cache: false,
   });

   return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:**
you can use the get request to send the output and receive via global `$_GET['msg']`
eg. `header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] . '?msg=' . $somemsg );`

**Method 2:** You can store some information regarding the current `hide()` and `show()` configuration  in the session before setting the redirect.
In the redirecting page, you can retrieve the config.